# Reference objects in containing package?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-3.x

I have a package, `spam`, that contains a contains the variable `_eggs` in `__init__.py`  In the same package, in `boiler.py`, I have the class `Boiler`.

In `Boiler`, I want to refer to `_eggs` in the package’s `__init__.py` file. Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate way to retrieve that value is via an explicit relative import:

```
from . import _eggs
```

However, one thing to keep in mind is that the following command line invocation will then fail to work:

```
python spam/boiler.py
```

The reason this won't work is the interpreter doesn't recognise any directly executed file as part of a package, so the relative import will fail.

However, with your current working directory set to the one containing the "spam" folder, you can instead execute the module as:

```
python -m spam.boiler
```

This gives the interpreter sufficient information to recognise where boiler.py sits in the module hierarchy and resolve the relative imports correctly.

This will only work with Python 2.6 or later - previous versions couldn't deal with explicit relative imports from **main** at all. (see [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for the gory details).

If you are simply doing `import spam.boiler` from another file, then that should work for any Python version that allows explicit relative imports (although it's possible Python 2.5 may need `from __future__ import absolute_imports` to correctly enable this feature)

Comment: "from . import _eggs" gives me an ImportError ("cannot import name _eggs") as does "from spam import _eggs".  I don't know if the rules changed here for Python 3, but neither solution works.

Comment: The only way I have found to do this would be to not do it at all; instead put such things in a module named _common.py or something and do "from ._common import _eggs".  Why I seemingly cannot do this with _eggs in `__init__.py` is beyond me.

Comment: Wait, how are you executing boiler.py? Via an "import spam.boiler" in another module? Via "python -m spam.boiler"? Via "python spam/boiler.py"? Or via "python boiler.py"? Either of the first two approaches should work, but the latter two will have problems (direct execution of modules located inside packages is considered inadvisable for very good reasons)

Comment: I did some experimentation, and it definitely works for me. That was with 2.7 though - which version is it that is giving you grief?

Comment: I was using Python 2.6 (still am); I wound up just using a module inside the package for it anyway, because I had other related code and that organization made sense.

Comment: Though I must have been doing something completely stupid or missed some detail, because now that I've tried it again... it works. *headdesk*